# Shell script 'not an identifier error'

Tags: shell, scripting, sqlplus

I have a script that should connect to oracle and run a query.

When I run the script I get the following error.

```
ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/10.2.0 
export ORACLE_HOME 
atm_test.sh: ORACLE_HOME^M: is not an identifier
```

My script looks like this.

```
ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/10.2.0; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=sid; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/bin; export PATH
...
```

In the shell when I `echo $ORACLE_HOME` it outputs `/app/oracle/product/10.2.0`

So I don't know what the issue could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script has Windows-style line endings.  Run it through `dos2unix` or a similar tool.  (Note that, unlike most filters, `dos2unix` overwrites the input file, so be careful.)

Are you using Cygwin?